# Create SPFX Webapp with React and styles from FluentUI

Tags: typescript, sharepoint, react-typescript

I am relatively new to programming with Typescript and React and thought I would make a webpart. How can I use the standard Sharepoint design in the web part?

In package.json there is only @fluentui/react, are there any other FluentUI libraries to use for the styles?

I am using react version 17.0.1 and @fluentui/react version ^17.204.0

I googled and found out that there is also @fluentui/react-northstar for the styles but when I try to install it with npm it doesn't show up in my package.json and in my node_module folder.

Comment: Hi Have you consulted the official UI documentation? It explains how to install the package.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/get-started/use-fabric-react-components

Comment: Yes, but according to FluentUI repo (https://github.com/microsoft/fluentui) office-ui-fabric-react became @fluentui/react and probably also the other @fluentui/react-* was created.

Comment: The things imported from the site of you of office-ui-fabric-react are also available in fluentui/react, thanks to you